# What happened to my install when I ran fdisk on /dev/sda2?

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk

I was trying to create an extended partition on `/dev/sda2` which was an empty primary partition on a hard drive. The partition table is `msdos`

I ran:

```
fdisk /dev/sda2
```

instead of fdisk `/dev/sda`

I then attempted to create a new gpt partition table on `/dev/sda2`. (was very sleepy)

At this point I rebooted, and fedora went into emergency mode. Here are pictures:

[image]

I proceeded to do login as root(emergency mode) and run :

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2 bs=16
```

Output of `journalctl -xb` : [READE ME](http://pastebin.com/raw/YWZDRzXC)

This is an almost fresh install, What is causing it to boot into emergency mode, and how can I fix it?

Background :
I am running fedora 24 with the only ill-understood change I made is to install the deadline scheduler using fedy

I use gnome primarily, but have installed xfce with plans to try it. 
Running:

```
su username 
switchdesk xfce
startx
```

Loads xfxe

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by removing that partition's entry from /etc/fstab

For reference: none of the actions I took were damaging to the empty partition, it was the fact that I deleted a partition which was listed in /etc/fstab

I apologize for bad formatting in the question. I typed out the question on my phone's browser.